# Activities manager software

Tags: windows, linux, project-management, time-management, productivity

I have many different pet projects (I would say around 5-6) and each one has its own scheduled tasks, routines, deadlines and specific requirements. So far I've got by, however I'd like to reduce inefficiencies and optimise the time spent on each project.

I would like to have an application that could manage all these projects, that's to say:

1. Keep track of all the deadlines in a calendar which is in sync with all the projects.
2. Keep track of the tasks required by each project at every specific deadline. This may consists of either repetitive tasks or a specific list of tasks.
3. Keep track of the progress of each project, a bar chart or another kind of visual take with percentages would be highly appreciated.
4. The program should also allow you to enter the time spent on each task and let you plot statistics about where the time has been spent. Ideally there should be an option to add the value per hour produced so that some meaningful financial considerations can be drawn.
5. Again, ideally, the program should have a scheduler to allocate time to be spent every week and the possibility to compare the plan with the effective results.
6. Free if possible, and available both on Linux and Windows

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Asana](https://asana.com/) seems like it might be a good fit for you.

I started asking the same question as you, and for a while asana worked very well.
Its been about a year since I've used it (single full-time job now) and I'm guessing they improved a lot over the past year.

Comment: Excellent, this solution meets almost all of my requirements! Thanks